# Eclipse RAP, Tabris: TableViewer does not work properly on iOS

Tags: eclipse-rap

I created a very small web application using a JFace `TableViewer`.
In the brower the table looks nice, but on iOS using Tabris the table columns are missing.

Please see the code [here](https://github.com/baumato/TabrisSandbox/blob/master/TabrisSandbox/src/org/tobbaumann/tabris/sandbox/Application.java).
And please compare the browser and iOS version [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/962415/browserAndiOS.jpg).
What am I missing? Maybe I have to change the CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Real" tables as you know them from the desktop are not supported yet, as they are not a common UI pattern on mobile devices.

Table, Tree and List are always displayed as a "List". You can have two columns: The first will be the main title Label, the second column will be used as a subtitle Label on the item. (Like in a Mail app, where you have the "From" in a big, bold font and the "Subject" in a smaller font below.)

So in your case I would concatenate the two dates into the first column and the subject into the second column.

Comment: Regarding your code: Use new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM) and shell.setMaximized( true ) to get a fullscreen App. In the upcoming Tabris release you will be able to setToolTip( string ) on the table to display a bar with a "title" for your Table widget.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Works fine. And yes, in the application I am currently writing, I have used SWT.NO_TRIM and setMaximized(true).  The referenced code was just an example to illustrate my question.